# Formatting a date from a string

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have looked at a number of other solutions on here, but can't seem to get this to work for my case.

I am consuming an API, from which some parts will be saved to core data, however the date format in the API doesn't match that of which core data expects,

The date that I am getting is in the format:

Jun 28, 2013 5:51:28 PM

I need to be able to sort my entity by this date in order to display the latest items. I tried the following format, but I can't seem to get a result that works, any ideas on how I can achieve this?

```
NSDate *createdDate = [key objectForKey:@"createdDate"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"mm/dd/yyyy hhmmss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:createdDate];
```

Comment: what you get date or string ??

Comment: you can change the date format before saving it to the core data..if you are not able to change the format..let us know in which format you are getting date in string or date ? so, we can answer your question..

Comment: I am receiving JSON data which shows the date in format

Jun 28, 2013 5:51:28 PM

Which as @wain mentions shouldn't be parsed as a date straight away, but should be stored as a string then parsed, I will check the format against the documentation as suggested

Comment: samo, samo, samo...  Boring, boring, boring...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createdDate` can't be an `NSDate`. If it was your code would crash rather than just not working. It must be an `NSString`.

```
NSString *createdDate = [key objectForKey:@"createdDate"];
```

Next, the date string you say you receive is `Jun 28, 2013 5:51:28 PM` which doesn't even slightly match the format you're trying to use of `mm/dd/yyyy hhmmss`. For a start the format has slashes and the date string doesn't. The format must match the string construction exactly. Read the date formatter format spec again and modify your format. I don't have it to hand but it will be something like `MMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss a` (don't just use that format, check it first).

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense, I was unsure of the slashes etc, I will check the documentation and then respond, thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks I was able to check this against the documentation and found the correct formate was 

[dateFormat setDateFormat:  @"MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a"]; I just need to sort out the locale now to adhere to the +1 hour for british summer time - thanks for your help

Comment: Wain I'm trying to figure this thing out too, and trying to look thru you're answers for help, any way you can take a peek at my Q real quick to possibly lend your expertise?  Thanks a lot!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675839/rkvaluetransformers-failed-transformation-of-value-to-nsdate?noredirect=1#comment40162652_25675839

Comment: So the way to know if it is an `NSDate` is for the code to crash?  Or is it the other way around, where if it's not `NSDate` then your code will crash?  Just wondering because I'm trying to solve a problem like this right now that I can't find answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675839/rkvaluetransformers-failed-transformation-of-value-to-nsdate?noredirect=1#comment40162652_25675839